# JavaScript - Read Bit Value, is single Bit On (1) or Off (0)?

Tags: javascript, binary, bit-manipulation, bitwise-operators, bit

In JavaScript, how can I know if a single Bit is On (1) or Off (0)?

```
function isBitOn(number, index)
{
  // ... ?
}

// Example:
let num = 13; // 1101

isBitOn(num, 0); // true   1
isBitOn(num, 1); // false  0
isBitOn(num, 2); // true   1
isBitOn(num, 3); // true   1
```

I know that in JavaScript we have [Bitwise Operations](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_bitwise.asp). But How can I use them, or use any other method, the read single Bit?

Comment: [Bitwise operators - JavaScript | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert the number to binary, then check the bits:

```js
function isBitOn(number, index) {
  let binary = number.toString(2);
  return (binary[(binary.length - 1) - index] == "1"); // index backwards
}

let num = 13; // 1101

console.log(isBitOn(num, 0));
console.log(isBitOn(num, 1));
console.log(isBitOn(num, 2));
console.log(isBitOn(num, 3));
```

Comment: This will not work unless you expect bits to be numbered from the most-significant to the least significant. Also  if the input number is not an integer the resulting string from calling `.toString(2)` will contain a "." character.

Comment: @GilEpshtain note that it produces the wrong results.

Comment: @Pointy the most-significant bit is always at the start of the resulting string. And yes, it won't work with decimals, but the result for the 13 provided in the question is correct.

Comment: @WaisKamal but note the expected results in the OP. Usually, in modern computing people expect bit 0 to be the *least* significant bit.

Comment: @Pointy do I get from you that the OP wants the bits from the right to left?

Comment: @WaisKamal yes, look at the sample code and the comments in the question.

Comment: @Pointy - In what cases this will not work? (except decimal)

Comment: @GilEpshtain with the modifications just made, it will work. Previously it interpreted the index backwards from your sample results.

Comment: Also the ternary is superfluous

Answer (score 3):

JavaScript retains the legacy of the C binary operators. You use the "index" to shift the value 1 to the left, and then you AND the result to the number you're interested in:

```js
function isBitOn(number, index) {
  return Boolean(number & (1 << index));
}
console.log(isBitOn(13, 0));
console.log(isBitOn(13, 1));
console.log(isBitOn(13, 2));
console.log(isBitOn(13, 3));
console.log(isBitOn(13, 4));
console.log(isBitOn(13, 5));
console.log(isBitOn(13, 6));
```

Note that that's the bitwise `&` operator, and not the `&&` short-circuit logical operator.

Also note that those operators treat the numbers as 32-bit integers, so it can't work for very large numbers.

Comment: What am I missing? lets test `num = 13` (13 is 1101) and `index = 2`. So `(1 << 2)` is 4 (4 is 0100). Now lets look at `(1101 & 0100)` is 0100. SO why when I run it I get 1 and not 0100. please help me understand

Comment: Are you running the current version? It converts the computed result to a boolean before returning. Any non-zero number when converted to boolean is `true`

Comment: If you run the version without that change, you get `1 0 4 8 0 0`

Comment: ok, this is a simple number to boolean conversion. I was thinking I'm missing something.

Comment: @GilEpshtain To get 0 and 1, you'd use `(number >>> index) & 1`