# Javascript - convert binary to decimal

Tags: javascript, binary, byte, bit

I'm using the solution provided here [Read bit value](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62246953/18660792) to convert 1 byte (8 bit - unsigned number from 0 to 255) to a boolean array, E.g 118 gives me:

```
boolArray = [false, true, true, false, true, true, true, false]
```

Now I need to convert it back to the decimal representation, If i create a binary from boolArray like this:

```
    binObj = []
    OutObj.map((obj) => {
      BoolToInt = obj.isActive ? 1 : 0
      binObj.push(BoolToInt)
    })
    binary = binObj.toString().replaceAll(',', '') // =>  01101110
```

how can I convert the binary "01101110" to decimal value 118?

If I use parseInt the result is 110 not 118

```
 parseInt('01101110', 2) => 110
```

am I doing something wrong?

I would get back 118 from 01101110, not 110.

Comment: FYI, `"false", "true"` are **strings**, (not boolean `false, true`) and will all evaluate to true.

Comment: Well 1101110 is 110 and not 118. (1*64+1*32+0*16+1*8+1*4+1*2+0*1 = 64+32+8+4+2 = 110). 118 is the reverted direction 1110110. read the array backwards.

Comment: I'm converting true to 1 and false to 0

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan you'r right, edited

Comment: @MoxxiManagarm yes! reversing the array did the trick!

Comment: It is actually noted in the answer you referenced `// index backwards`. But one one wonders why you made a boolean array when `0` and `1` are stable boolean analogs

Answer (score 2):

A more compact way of doing decimal<->binary boolean arrays:

```js
console.log([...(118).toString(2)].map(i=>i==='1'))
console.log(
  parseInt([true,true,true,false,true,true,false].map(i=>+i).join(''),2)
)
```

Comment: `Number()` isn't really necessary here because `118` already is a number. `[...(118).toString(2)]` or `[...118..toString(2)]` will do.